# Problems with bibliography file in LaTex

Tags: latex, bibliography, biblatex

Bibliography doesn't show up.

My .bib file is okay I think but when I compile the main file bibliography doesn't show.

I don't know what's wrong, please help.

Important parts of code in my main file.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[
 backend=biber,
 style=ieee
 ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
...

\begin{document}
 ...
\chapter*{Bibliography}

\printbibliography
...
\end{document}
```

And my bibliography file has some references like this one.

```
@article{1,
author = "Diomidis Spinellis",
title = "{Being a Software Developer}",
journal = "IEEE Software",
volume = "35",
number = "4",
month = {August},
year = "2018",
pages = "4-7",
doi = {10.1109/MS.2018.2801555}
}
```

Comment: If I add `\cite{1}` to your document, it works fine for me. How do you compile? Did you run `biber` between the tex runs?

Comment: @samcarter When I run biber the console output has this message: ERROR - Cannot find control file 'biblio.bcf'! - Did latex run successfully on your .tex file before you ran biber?

Comment: Well, the code you show won't compile because of the `...` and the missing `\cite{1}` command. If I add those the code compiles

Comment: @samcarter I have added \cite{1} but still the biber file shows the text above. I am using TeXworks.

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you would show some compilable code in your questions to make sure we start from the same point.

Answer (score -2):

For this kind of message:

> ERROR - Cannot find control file `biblio.bcf`!

Try to also check if you chose the correct corresponding backend in your text editor.

E.g., with Texmaker, you choose "Biber" or "BibTeX" for the field "Bib(La)TeX" , in Tools/configure Texmaker

[image]